# salvando dados de autenticação no localStorage react js

Tags: javascript, react, localstorage, axios, auth

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Reactjs e utilizando axios para trabalhar com as requisições e preciso manter os dados do usuário salvos no localStorage, porem esta faltando alguma coisa no meu código, pois esta dando undefined no valor onde era para estar os dados que preciso.

Segue o código, e meu package.json

Arquivo index de Singup

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
var querystring = require('querystring');

import api from "../../services/api";
import { login } from "../../services/auth";
import logo from '../../../../../styles/image/logo.svg'

class SignIn extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: "" };
    }

    handleSignIn = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = this.state;
        if (!email || !password) {
        this.setState({ error: "Preencha e-mail e senha para continuar!" });
        } else {
            try {            
                const response = await api.post("login", querystring.stringify({ email, password }));            
                login(response.data.token);           
                this.props.history.push("/menu");
            } catch (err) {
                this.setState({
                error:
                    "Houve um problema com o login, verifique suas credenciais. T.T"
                });
            }
        }        
    };

    render() {
        return ( 
                <div className="row"> 
                    <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <div className='espaceblank'>
                            {/* ESPAÇO PARA SER ARRUMADO NO CSS */}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <img src={logo} width='120' height='120' alt='logo' />                        
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
                        <p className="">Bem vindo!</p>
                                <form onSubmit={this.handleSignIn}>
                                {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label>Email:</label>
                                    <input
                                        type="email"
                                        placeholder="Endereço de e-mail"
                                        onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
                                        className='form-control'
                                    />
                                    <br />
                                    <label>Senha:</label>
                                    <input
                                        type="password"
                                        placeholder="Senha"
                                        onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
                                        className='form-control'
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className='row'>
                                    <div className='col-md-4'>                            
                                        <button type="submit" className='btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light m-r-10'>Entrar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>         
                    </div>                          
                </div>
        ) 
    }
}

export default withRouter(SignIn);
```

Arquivo da api

```
import axios from "axios";
import { getToken } from "./auth.js";

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://localhost/aplicacao",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});

api.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
    const token = getToken();
    if (token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
});

export default api;
```

Arquivo auth

```
export const TOKEN_KEY = localStorage;
export const isAuthenticated = () => localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY) !== null;
export const getToken = () => localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
export const login = token => {
    localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, token);
};
export const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
};
```

Arquivo package.json

```
{
  "name": "teste1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "test": "jest ./test"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./test/enzyme.setup.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-check-auth": "^0.2.0-alpha.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4"
  }
}
```

Imagem DevTools
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Opa Helder, não observei no seu código onde de fato é chamado a função login do arquivo auth.

Comment: Opa André, obrigado por perguntar, eu fiz upload do código do arquivo errado, tenho dois iguais onde um já esta pronto e estou trabalhado no outro. Mas agora esta corrigido, a função login é chamada no try catch da função handleSignIn, no arquivo index de Singup.